# filter then query on ElasticSearch 8.6.2

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using ElasticSearch 8.6.2 to power a search application. For one use case we are running a fuzzy search but the performance of this is not great at higher concurrencies.

We tried modelling the search query in the following way:

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "fuzzy": {
          "valCol": {
              "value": "dhsaads"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "fil1": [23,123,13]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "fil2": [443,121,532]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The results are expected but the latency is quite high for this when running at higher TPS loads. We notice Disk I/O to de a bottleneck here. From the query profiler on Kibana what we could understand is that the filter operations are executed after the fuzzy match. Is there a way to run the filter queries before this to limit the search space? On older versions found the `filtered` clause but could not find an equivalent in the newer versions.

Any other optimisations that could help here would also be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you see that filters where executed after must? Can you profile a [profiled response](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html) of your query?

Comment: In the Search profiler on Kibana you can see the different operations it does. To confirm filters are run after must we can use some query which doesn't result any result and then confirm that filter is not executed.

Comment: Tldr; You dont control the clause order of a query https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order.
For optimisation of search you may refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html

Answer (score 0):

The [post filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html#post-filter) can solve your problem.

An example:

```
GET /shirts/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": { "brand": "gucci" } 
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "colors": {
      "terms": { "field": "color" } 
    },
    "color_red": {
      "filter": {
        "term": { "color": "red" } 
      },
      "aggs": {
        "models": {
          "terms": { "field": "model" } 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": { 
    "term": { "color": "red" }
  }
}
```

Comment: not really, the problem is about optimising a query, not an aggregation

Comment: I think it helps in atleast the part where we want to limit search space by the filtered terms.